# Prove that this function is Riemann integrable using upper and lower sums

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration

Let $f: [0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{if } 0 \le x < 1, \\
0 & \text{if } 1 \le x \le 2.
\end{cases}
$$
For any $\epsilon>0$, let $P_\epsilon = \{ 0, 1-\epsilon, 1, 2 \}$ be the partition of $[0,2]$.  Compute $U(f,P_\epsilon) - L(f,P_\epsilon)$.  Is $f$ Riemann integrable?  If yes, compute $\int_0^2 f$.

This is what I did.
$$U(f, P_\epsilon) = (1-\epsilon) \sup_{[0,1-\epsilon]} f + \epsilon \sup_{[1-\epsilon,1]} f + 1 \cdot \sup_{[1,2]} f = (1 - \epsilon)^3 + \epsilon,$$
$$L(f, P_\epsilon) = (1-\epsilon) \inf_{[0,1-\epsilon]} f + \epsilon \inf_{[1-\epsilon,1]} f + 1 \cdot \inf_{[1,2]} f = 0.$$
Is it right?  I think my work was wrong.  For me, this function is Riemann integrable, and I had to choose a different partition (from what the problem gave me) to make $U(f,P_\epsilon)-L(f,P_\epsilon) < \epsilon$ (and go to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$).  What should $P_\epsilon$ be?

Thank you.

Comment: This function is Riemann integrable. For most functions including this one the number of pieces in your partition needs to go to infinity to show convergence.

Comment: Maybe the question should read: prove that this function is Riemann integradable by using Upper and Lower sums...

Comment: @dmtri Thank you.  I'll fix it.

Comment: @quarague Was my work computing the upper and lower sums correct? The $P_\epsilon$ partition was given to me as part of the question.